# Why is my div hidden behind position:absolute images?

Tags: html, css

In this code, I put two images over each other using absolute positioning, but the second div with class `row` seems to be hidden behind the images. How can I fix that and make it appear in its correct place (after the images)?

```css
.composition {
  position: relative;
}

.img-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.img-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="composition">
        <img src="imgs/lenses.jpg" class="img-fluid img-1" alt="" />
        <img src="imgs/mountain-1.jpg" class="img-fluid img-2" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita praesentium inventore iusto rem perspiciatis impedit.
</div>
```

Comment: You can't with the given markup, because the absolute positioned images is taken out of flow, and their parent will collapse to 0, and is the reason the 2nd `row` item is hidden.

Comment: The best you could do is add `margin-top` or `padding-top` to the second row that's the same height as the images. As @LGSon said, `absolute` takes the elements out of the document flow, so there is no reference for any element to stack against.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, the absolute positioning on the images is causing .composition to not have a height and the div below it to collapse under the images.

Why do both images need to be absolutely positioned?  Leave one image without the absolute positioning so the .composition has a height of the image.  The second image can be positioned absolutely to cover the first.

With the first image staying in the flow and keeping a height, the second div will remain below the images.

```css
.composition {
  position: relative;
}

.img-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="composition">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/100/100" class="img-fluid img-1" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1021/100/100" class="img-fluid img-2" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita praesentium inventore iusto rem perspiciatis impedit.
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change the position:absolute to position:relative for images.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .composition {
        position: relative;
    }
    .img-1 {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100px; 
        height: 150px;
    }
    .img-2 {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100px;
        height: 150px;
    } 
</style>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="composition">
            <img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/lAgAAOSwWAhcFLHg/s-l300.jpg" class="img-fluid img-1" alt="" />
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1bHL-HroyjayQ-OzEENg90I7a6CdtNRnn6l7KdSC8LlXr7H5w" class="img-fluid img-2" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita praesentium inventore iusto rem perspiciatis impedit.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, now you changed the intended layout completely. The absolute positioned elements are just that for a reason, to overlap, and making them relative doesn't answer what is asked, which is _"Why is my div hidden behind `position:absolute` images?"_.